# Post Data Into this type of format?

Tags: ios, swift, post

I am not getting how to POST this type of data into webservice

```
{
  "customer_id":"",
  "customer_message": " entered by user",
  "discount_amount": "",
  "ip_address":"1.0.10.22",
  "billing_address": {
    "first_name": "hello",
    "last_name": "world",
    "company": "",
    "street_1": "45 W test",
    "street_2": "",
    "city": "London",
    "state": "Texas",
    "zip": "123456",
    "country": "United States",
    "country_iso2": "US",
    "phone": "",
    "email": "xyz@example.com"
  },
  "shipping_addresses": [
    {
      "first_name": "rest",
      "last_name": "Mctest",
      "company": "Test Address",
      "street_1": "rest test",
      "street_2": "",
      "city": "test",
      "state": "test",
      "zip": "12345",
      "country": "United States",
      "country_iso2": "US",
      "phone": "",
      "email": "xyzer@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "products": [
    {
      "product_id": 5448,
      "quantity": 2
    }
  ]
```

I am not getting how to POST this type of data into webservice.
Please help me

i am doing this type of data now i have to post this type. Can anyone post this type.

```
let aParam = ["email": Email, "password":Password] as [String:Any]
```

Comment: the format you are using is already correct and the format you want is just the json format of your format. if you convert your format to json it would just look the same. use `JSONSerialisation` to convert array to json

Comment: Are you using alamofire? or you are doing with URLSession implementation?

Comment: i am using URLSession @AnkitJayaswal let aHeader = ["Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
        
        let aParam = ["email": Email, "password": Password] as [String: Any]
        
        let leadPath = "http://www.test.com/login_user"
        
        ServiceManager.execute(method: .post, path: leadPath, param: aParam, header: aHeader, completion: completion)

Comment: Can you share the code you are using currently, so that problem you are facing can be easily visible?

Comment: like above i am sending aParam in the form of dictionary , now i have to send array and dictionary inside dictionary, i am not getting how to use this there in aParam? @AnkitJayaswal

Comment: In dictionary `[String: Any]`, Any can refer all types string, array and dictionary. You just need to set `"Content-Type": "application/json"`.

Comment: con you send me hint of code like i send in aParam @AnkitJayaswal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking parameters as `[String: Any]`, where Any denotes each type of data types. Say String, Array and Dictionary.

**For example,**

```
let aParam: [String: Any] = ["customer_id": "",
                             "customer_message": "",
                             "billing_address": ["first_name" : "hello",
                                                 "last_name" : "world",
                                                 "company" : "",
                                                 "street_1" : "45 W test"],
                             "shipping_addresses": [
                                ["first_name" : "hello",
                                 "last_name" : "world",
                                 "company" : "",
                                 "street_1" : "45 W test"]
                            ],
                             "products": [
                                ["product_id" : 5448,
                                 "quantity" : 2],
                                ["product_id" : 5450,
                                 "quantity" : 1]
                            ]
                            ]
```

And complex json structure would be handle with content-type as JSON, so:

**You just need to update your header as:**

```
let aHeader = ["Content-Type" : "application/json"]
```

Hope this will help